# Problem with making fields required in strapi

Tags: postgresql, strapi

After I marked a few fields as required, I can no longer start the server. In the postgres logs I can see it's trying to drop constraints that were never there. The errors are about the fields I've tried to mark as required.

```
2020-01-31 12:59:06.753 UTC [372] ERROR:  constraint "awardscompetitions_place_unique" of relation "awardscompetitions" does not exist
2020-01-31 12:59:06.753 UTC [372] STATEMENT:  alter table "awardscompetitions" drop constraint "awardscompetitions_place_unique"
2020-01-31 12:59:06.754 UTC [369] ERROR:  constraint "awardscompetitions_price_unique" of relation "awardscompetitions" does not exist
2020-01-31 12:59:06.754 UTC [369] STATEMENT:  alter table "awardscompetitions" drop constraint "awardscompetitions_price_unique"
```

Does anyone know how can I prevent droping these not existing constraints?

Comment: Hello! can you please provide exact steps to reproduce your issue please. It will help me to help you.

Comment: The cause might be that you have created some documents that don't respect the required validation. Can you try removing the required validation by editing the file manually restart your server and delete the corresponding documents. Adding the required validation back should work after that.